# Why is the Tabulator rowTapHold method not working with iOS devices?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I can't seem to figure out why the `Tabulator rowTapHold()` method will not work with mobile devices.  The following is my very simple code snippet:

**HTML**

```
<link href="~/css/Dailies/tabulator.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="example-table"></div>
<script src="~/js/Dailies/tabulator.js"></script>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
var tabledata = [
    { Laborcode: "select a code", Memo: "test row #1" },
    { Laborcode: "select a code", Memo: "test row #2" },
    { Laborcode: "select a code", Memo: "test row #3" },
    { Laborcode: "select a code", Memo: "test row #4" },
    { Laborcode: "select a code", Memo: "test row #5" }
];

var laborCodes = ["1001", "1002", "1003"];
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    columns: [
        { title: "Labor Code", field: "Laborcode", responsive: 0, hozAlign: "center", editor: "select", editorParams: function (cell) { values: []; return { values: laborCodes }; } },
        { title: "Memo", field: "Memo", responsive: 0, hozAlign: "left", editor: "input" },
    ],
    data: tabledata,
    height: "100%",
    layout: "fitDataFill",
    reactiveData: true, //enable reactive data
    responsiveLayout: "collapse",
    rowContextMenu: [
        {
            label: "Add Row",
            action: function (e, row) { row.getTable().addRow({ Laborcode: "select a code", Memo: "add a memo" }, false); }
        },
        {
            label: "Delete Row",
            action: function (e, row) { row.delete(); }
        }
    ],
    rowTapHold: [
        {
            label: "Add Row",
            action: function (e, row) { row.getTable().addRow({ Laborcode: "select a code", Memo: "add a memo" }, false); }
        },
        {
            label: "Delete Row",
            action: function (e, row) { row.delete(); }
        }
    ]
});
```

The `Tabulator rowContextMenu` method works just fine in the desktop browsers I've tested.  I need the comparable `rowTapHold` method to work for mobile devices.

As always, any assistance is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

By removing the `Tabulator moveableRows` method, I was able to get the `rowTapHold` method to work with Android devices.  I am still unable to get the `rowTapHold` feature to work with iOS devices.

I have added a second (very simple) `Tabulator` example at jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0fqhupox/.

Comment: If you think you have found a bug, please report it on the project GitHub repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because the ***rowTapHold*** option is intended to be used as a callback, so you must pass a function to the option.

You appear to be passing an array of menu options to the ***rowTapHold*** property. This does not support menu triggering, it only supports a callback function that should be run when the trigger happens.

If pass a function into this property, you will see it is called when a user tapHolds a row

The [Row Callbacks Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/callbacks#row) explains the correct use of the row events callbacks.

#### Update

As of version 4.8 of Tabulator *(released today)* context menus now automatically add a binding for `tapHold` on mobile devices to improve mobile functionality

Comment: Oli, Many thanks to you and the other contributors who helped bring Tabulator v4.8 to fruition.   I am pleased to report my issue was completely resolved.